# jQuery & SQL Server without using .NET or PHP

Tags: html, sql-server, jquery-ui, jquery

I am new to jQuery, and creating a web page to teach myself how to do some things with it.  Among other things, I would like to read from a SQL Server database, write to it, and call stored procedures.

A feature of my test page is to have a button on the top half of the page that you click on & would call the stored procedure, and the bottom of this web page to read & refresh as data is written to a table (*Note: since most of the actions are subsequent to calling the stored procedure, I am considering using a trigger on a SQL Server table which will write to the table being refreshed*).

Using jQuery 1.9.1, jquery-ui 1.10.2, and Microsoft SQL Server 2008 & 2012. Currently testing with the Express versions of SQL Server. I am limited in that I will not be able to use ASP.NET or PHP in order to create a web service.

I am trying to find a tutorial, step-by-step, or other reference/guide that would:

1. let me know if what I want to do is possible (given the limits I will have),
2. and provide some instruction on how to go about it.

I've been able to create a web service that retrieves RSS data, and find a number of how-to's for those.  Ajax is used to retrieve that data, but I have not been able to find any helpful instruction that does not use ASP.NET or PHP to do so.

I would appreciate any thoughts, instruction or direction in using jQuery in reading from & writing to a SQL Server database.

Thanks!

Comment: The only thing I can think of that might be of use is Node.js, but I'm not sure exactly if that is sufficient. Otherwise you will need some kind of server-based language (PHP, ASP, Perl/CGI, Java/Servlets, or an XML-RPC API or similar) to actually do the database calls.

Comment: SNL had a skit called "Bad Idea Jeans".  I wouldn't recommend this.  You need a middle-tier, even a most basic one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're a little bit off.

You can use jQuery Javascript to invoke service methods on your web server, which will, in turn, invoke a stored procedure and return the result to the browser.  However, you cannot directly work with SQL from Javascript.

That being said, Microsoft has a component of their .net framework called "Entity Framework" which does some of the steps for you.

The basic steps are like this:

(1) Create a stored procedure in SQL.  Let's call it my_proc.

(2) Create an MVC application in Visual Studio.

(2) Create an "Entity Data Model" in your MVC application.  Be sure to import my_proc into your model.  This will create a class that represents the results of a stored procedure call with the columns as properties.

(3) In the same application, create a controller with a "JsonResult" method.  It should look like this:

```
public JsonResult CallMyProc()
{
    MyEntities entities = new MyEntities();
    var result = entities.my_proc("a", "b", "c");
    return result;
}
```

(4) Use jQuery AJAX to invoke CallMyProc.  The data will be serialized as JSON and can be deserialized into a Javascript object that you can work with.

That should get you started.

Answer (score 2):

This is not possible.  The SQL database exists on the server, and the javascript/jquery code runs on the client (web browser). Older versions of SQL Server contained the ability to create web services directly (HTTP Endpoints) but that was, appropriately, removed.

So you will need some type of server-side code to create a webservice that can be called via javascript and can, in turn, make calls to the database.

Comment: +1 for Microsoft removing the http sql server end points.  (and for you mentioning it!)

Comment: Could something be built in SQL (2008 R2 or 2012) that could be called from jQuery?  I was wondering if BIDS (or whatever its called once everyone knows it as BIDS) could be used to develop it.  I had already stumbled on (and quickly off) the HTTP endpoints.

Comment: Yes, something could be built using BIDS (Business Intelligence Development Studio), but that's not "in SQL Server".  Everyone is telling you that you need a middle-tier (built, for example, in .NET), and BIDS is just a set of tools for building a .NET middle-tier that is specifically designed to talk to SQL Server.  But it's no different than what everyone else is proposing.

Comment: Sorry for not asking a "better" question; having not been doing much .net development in a while, I wasn't sure exactly what I was asking.  Given the limitation of the client not being able to load a .net framework, I was unsure of how to go about developing anything that could be accessed by jQuery & where that middle tier could be deployed to.  I had stumbled upon the Endpoints & found out that it was removed, but how it functioned is very much like how the solution I need would need to work.  Thanks for the information.